# TableView appearing differently for only one viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having many `UITableViewController`s in my app, and only one of them is appearing different from the others..

Normal :

[image: Normal]

Different :

[image: Different]

Header and Footer are displayed very differently!! And, there is no customised views behind the scenes.. Both are created from scratch as `UITableViewController`s

Comment: One looks like grouped table, the other not.

Comment: can you post some code(tableview datasource and delegate methods)

Comment: @MaxPevsner, well, actually, yes. First are grouped prototype cells. Second aren't..

Comment: @MaxPevsner, and I have the answer.. Thanks very much

Comment: @MaxPevsner. If I may ask, how do we separate footer into different lines?

Comment: @MaxPevsner. Was able to get them as separate lines.. :)